# Salesforce CDP Ingestion API Example

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce-cdp, cdp

We are trying to use the new Salesforce CDP ingestion api but are getting undefined errors when loading our .yaml file.

I have confirmed that we have the proper requirements outlined [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_ingestion_api_schema_req.htm&type=5) and also validated my OAS 3.0 on https://editor.swagger.io/

Anyone have any examples we can use to validate our file? Not sure what objects are/n't required in OAS 3.0 for Salesforce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example. This was my first time using YML/YMAL files and I found spacing is very important. Got undefined errors for spacing issues.

```
      openapi: 3.0.1
      components:
        schemas:
          owner:
            type: object
            required:
              - id
              - name
              - region
              - gender
              - createddate
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
                format: int64
              name:
                type: string
                maxLength: 50
              region:
                type: string
                maxLength: 50
              gender:
                type: string
                maxLength: 10
              createddate:
                type: string
                format: date-time
          pet:
            type: object
            required:
              - id
              - species
              - name
              - breed1
              - gender
              - createddate
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
                format: int64
              species:
                type: string
                maxLength: 100
              name:
                type: string
                maxLength: 50
              breed1:
                type: string
                maxLength: 50
              breed2:
                type: string
                maxLength: 50
              gender:
                type: string
                maxLength: 10
              createddate:
                type: string
                format: date-time
```

Comment: thanks, @HiMyNameIsEfren ! This worked. I just switched out my fields and worked like a charm. You saved me a lot of headache.